# Why does calling this Javascript function submit my form?

Tags: javascript

I have a form validation script. Unless all conditions are met, the ambiguous function associated with `form.onclick` returns false (form doesn't submit). I have another function which upon error will append an error message to the errorLog div.

```
  function addError (msg) {
    msg = document.createTextNode(msg);
    br = document.createElement("br");
    errorLog.append(msg);
    errorLog.append(br);
    alert("yes");
  }
```

If an error is found, calling this function submits the form. The script doesnt even enter the function, it simply submits the data and refreshes. I realize there is an error in the function, but i cant seem to figure it out.

edit: more of my code

```
  form.onsubmit = function () 
  {
    if (nameCheck(fname, lname))
      return true;

    return false; 
  };
```

function that checks if "name" field is valid:

```
function nameCheck (fname,lname)
{
  if (("/\d/").test(fname) || ("/\d/").test(lname))
  {
    addError('Your name cannot contain numbers.');
    valid = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: "The script doesnt even enter the function, it simply submits the data and refreshes." - hmm, then that would explain that then?

Comment: That function shouldn't submit the form. Please post how you handle the submit event. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes i have checked for other errors. I tried simply logging the error message to the console instead, and that worked. Only using this _addError()_ function causes this.

Comment: Maybe it's because you never defined `fname` and `lname` (in `form.onsubmit`)?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/btL45mj2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not stopping the form from submitting.

Use [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to temporarily stop the form from submitting, then if the form is correct use [`this.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) to finish submitting the form

```
form.onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (nameCheck(fname, lname)) {
        this.submit();
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
};
```

Also, `nameCheck` will never resolve true, as it doesnt return anything. It should look like this

```
function nameCheck (fname,lname) {
  if (("/\d/").test(fname) || ("/\d/").test(lname)) {
    addError('Your name cannot contain numbers.');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `preventDefault()` the same thing as `return false`?

Comment: But `return false` in event handlers behaves like `event.preventDefault`. It would be different for event listeners, though.

Comment: @humble.rumble Interesting. Can you provide a fiddle demonstrating that behavior? If all code is synchronous, that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @humble.rumble: That doesn't prove anything. Of course it's not possible to prevent the event in an async callback (because the event already took place). https://jsfiddle.net/1y302nae/ shows that it works fine, even for long running processes.

Comment: I think you should use `return false;` instead since it's a lot more simple.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do it is this:

```
form.onsubmit = function () {
    if (("/\d/").test(fname) || ("/\d/").test(lname)) {
        addError('Your name cannot contain numbers.');
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
};
```

and this way, you don't need the `checkName()` part, but you still need the `addError()` part.